# What am i doing wrong when solving this differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics, error-function

$$
f(x) = \frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[e^y]}{\frac{d}{dx}[e^y]}
$$

Given that $f(x) = cx$

$$
\frac{c}{2}x^2 + k_1 = \ln(e^y y')
$$

$$
k_2\int e^{\frac{c}{2}x^2} dx = e^y
$$

$$
y = \ln(k_2\int e^{\frac{c}{2}x^2} dx)
$$

Therefore

$$
y'^2 - cxy' + y'' = 0
$$

$$
y' = \frac{c}{2}x \pm \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4}- y''}
$$

$$
\frac{e^{\frac{c}{2}x^2}}{\int e^{\frac{c}{2}x^2} dx} = \frac{c}{2}x \pm \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4}x^2- y''}
$$

Yet when $c=4$

$$
\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{2x^2}}{\operatorname{erfi}(\sqrt{2}x)+c} = 2x \pm\sqrt{4x^2 + 8e^{2x^2}\frac{e^{2x^2}-\sqrt{2\pi}x\operatorname{erfi}(\sqrt{2}x)}{\pi \operatorname{erfi}(\sqrt{2}x)^2}}
$$

Is not correct, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, but if i graph the function they do not equal

Comment: You have the solution, $y(x)$.  What is your goal?

Comment: @Dr.MV Just needed to make sure i wasn't hallucinating when i saw that the two graphs didn't equal eachother

Comment: Eric ... per my "Answer," the solution does _not_ involve the error function when $C>0$.  That is the source of your concern, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Using the **very long way**, assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$,$$f(x) = \frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[e^y]}{\frac{d}{dx}[e^y]}$$ finally write $$y''-y'^2-y' f(x)=0$$ which eventually allows reduction order setting $z=y'$. So, if $f(x)=c x$, the solution of $z'-z^2-z f(x)=0$ is $$z=\frac{2 \sqrt{c} e^{\frac{c x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{c}
   x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+2 \sqrt{c} k_1} $$ and finally $$y=\log \left(\sqrt{2 \pi } \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{c} x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+2
   \sqrt{c} k_1\right)+k_2$$ The solution can be checked since $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[e^y]=2 c^{3/2} x e^{\frac{c x^2}{2}+k_2}$$ $$\frac{d}{dx}[e^y]=2 \sqrt{c} e^{\frac{c x^2}{2}+k_2}$$ $$\frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[e^y]}{\frac{d}{dx}[e^y]}=cx=f(x)$$

Using the **short way** (as suggested by chu), define $z=\frac{d}{dx}[e^y]$ and the equation write $$\frac{z'}{z}=cx$$ so $\log(z)=\frac c2 x^2+k_1$, that is to say $z=k_1 e^{\frac c2 x^2}$ and then the gaussian integral and the final result.

Answer (score 0):

$(e^{y(x)})'=k_2e^{\frac12Cx^2}$ implies $e^{y(x)}=k_2\int_a^xe^{\frac12Ct^2}dt+k_3$, where $k_3=e^{y(a)}$ and which for $C>0$ does not involve the error function.

Then,

$$y(x)=\ln\left(k_2\int_a^xe^{\frac12Ct^2}dt+k_3\right)$$

Comment: so therefore does this mean for y'' that where will be a constant in the denominator? and this is the sorce of my problem?

Comment: No.  The source of the problem is the mis-interpretation that the integral solution embeds the error function.  The error function has integrand $exp(-t^2/2)$.  Here, the integrand is $exp(+t^2/2)$

Comment: That is, one could add the assumption that $k_3=0$.  But, for $C>0$, there is no error function.

Answer (score 0):

Why does this not reduce to: y'' + (1-cx)y'=0?

Comment: Very good point, indeed ! $+1$

Comment: Why has the +1 I got earlier been revoked?

Comment: I really don't know ! The problem of downvotes is quite serious since, quite often, good answers and good comments suffer of strange attitudes. Don't worry too much about that. You will get good reputation points soon, I am sure. Cheers :-)

Comment: I just need to get it above 50 so that I can comment instead of writing answers! Best wishes.

Comment: @chu 

$$
f(x) = \frac{y''}{y'} + y' 
$$
using quadratic formula
$$
y'^2 - f(x) y' + y''
$$

$$
y' = \frac{f(x)}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{f(x)^2}{4} - y''}
$$

You can therefore find your way back quite easily

It does reduce to $y'' + (1-cx)y' = 0$ but im trying to view it another way.